# how to Migrate Date_ADD method into Db2 for dynamic values

Tags: mysql, database, db2

how to Migrate Date_ADD method into Db2 for dynamic values
 `where updatedDate BETWEEN  ? AND DATE_ADD(?, Interval 1 day)`
I need to run a dateadd function that will minus 1 DAY to current date

SQL has a function called dateadd, but it appears DB2 does not have this function. IS there anything equivalent to this function? If so, can someone post a syntax example?

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DB2 you can directly add days ( eg. date + 10 days ) , months ( eg. date + 10 months) and years just like arithmetic addition.

The statement actually worked for me in DB2:

Birthdate + 52 Years as AGE 52_DATE

reference: http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1637371-Help-Is-there-a-DATEADD-function-in-DB2